# State space for Markov chain.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

I'm trying to do this exercise from Probability by John Walsh:

*Let ${X_{n}, n = 0,1, 2, ... }$ be a Markov chain whose transition probabilities
MAY NOT be stationary. Define $X'_{n}$ to be the n-tuple $X'=(X_{0},. .. , X_{n})$. Show
that $(X'_{n})$ is a Markov chain with STATIONARY transition probabilities. (What is its
state space?)*

If I apply the stationarity condition I should obtain something like:

$P(X'_{n+1}=j|X'_{n}=i)=P(X'_{1}=j|X'_{0}=i).$

But, for example, the values that would take $X'_{n}$ are n-tuples meanwhile the values for $X'_{0}$ are just 1-tuples.

I want to find a "common" state space for the chain and show the claimed stationary condition.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there some primes missing in the definition?  Should it perhaps say, "Define $X'$ by $X'_n=(X_0,X_1,\dots,X_n)$. Show $(X_n')$ is a Markov chain with stationary transition probabilities."  I can't understand the question as written.

Comment: Yes, you are right.